# How to preserve drive device paths for AWS EC2 instance between reboots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, fstab

I rebooted a `m5d.xlarge` EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (xenial) using `shutdown -r`.

Upon reboot, various drive mounts defined in `/etc/fstab` did not line up with the device assignments given to them initially.

This caused various services to fail, which rely upon the drive mount with the assigned name containing specific data associated with that name.

In this case, `/data` needed to contain what is normally expected to be in `/data`, and not some other drive mount, like `/foo` or `/bar` or `/whatever-else`.

Running `lsblk` helped with manually redefining the `/etc/fstab` file to reflect the new device assignments and bringing services back online.

**Problem**: My worry is that rebooting will randomly reassign device labels to drive mounts, and this problem could or will occur again when the server requires rebooting.

**Question**: How do I ensure that drive mounts and their respective device paths are preserved between reboots, without needing manual (re)intervention?

---

**Edit**: The `c5_m5_checks_script.sh` script referenced in the answer provided below returns the following information:

```
# ./c5_m5_checks_script.sh 
------------------------------------------------

OK     NVMe Module is installed and available on your instance


ERROR  NVMe Module is not loaded in the initramfs image.
        - Please run the following command on your instance to recreate initramfs:
        # sudo update-initramfs -c -k all


OK     ENA Module with version 2.0.3K is installed and available on your instance


OK     fstab file looks fine and does not contain any device names.

------------------------------------------------
```

I don't understand the last `OK` statement, as the `fstab` file contains device names. Or Amazon's use of the term "device names" means something different from the device names in the `fstab` file, perhaps?

To give a specific and concrete example of the nature of the problem, I have an `/etc/fstab` that looks like this:

```
...
/dev/nvme2n1    /staging        ext4    defaults,nofail 0       0
/dev/nvme3n1    /data   ext4    defaults,nofail 0       0
...
```

However, `lsblk` shows that these two volumes are mounted to each other's device ID:

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme2n1     259:0    0     1T  0 disk /staging
nvme3n1     259:3    0   512G  0 disk /data
```

In reality, `nvme2n1` is the 1T volume `/data`, and `nvme3n1` is the 512G volume `/staging`.

Something unknown happens between reboots which reassigns the underlying drives to a permutation of the available device IDs.

The only way I know to fix this is to manually `umount` these two volumes, edit `/etc/fstab`, and `mount` them again.

**Bounty question**: Is there a permanent fix that would let me use a different and permanent identifier in `/etc/fstab`, which persists consistently between reboots?

Comment: What did they change from / to?

Comment: Root did not change. Only those external volumes added via the AWS console and the command line.

Comment: I'll restate - what were the paths before the change, and what were they after the change. This might help work out why it changed. For example I know that nVME and the new instances gives devices new names, and I have a solution AWS suggested, but that might not be your problem. Please edit your question to be a bit more precise if the existing answer wasn't enough for you.

Answer (score 5):

AWS has a tool to convert EBS volume device names in /etc/fstab to their UUID values: [c5_m5_checks_script.sh](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/EC2/C5M5InstanceChecks/c5_m5_checks_script.sh)

The script also checks that the NVMe module is loaded in your OS image, but your newer instance type would not have launched if that was not present.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `LABEL=` or `UUID=` in `/etc/fstab`?

You can use `blkid` to find out corresponding labels and UUIDs. Even more info in `man fstab` of course:

> It's also possible to use PARTUUID= and PARTLABEL=. These partitions identifiers are supported for example for GUID Partition Table (GPT).
>
> See mount(8), blkid(8) or lsblk(8) for more details about device identifiers.
>
> Note that mount(8) uses UUIDs as strings. The string representation of the UUID should be based on lower case characters.

Comment: If you could clarify or otherwise flesh out your answer, that would be very useful. If you're just asking a general question, maybe add a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: man `fstab` has even an example: `LABEL=t-home2   /home      ext4    defaults,auto_da_alloc      0  2`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my case was to use the symlinks instead (thanks to one of my colleagues):

When you attach volumes to an instance you specify the names of the drives as /dev/sd* (in AWS console or Terraform for example).
If you log in to your instance you will see that these are symlinks that point to nvmeXn1, nvmeYn1, etc...
And the symlinks still point to the right drive after the instance reboot even if the drive's name has changed.

**My case:**

**Before reboot**

```
  :~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme1n1      259:4    0  500G  0 disk
nvme2n1      259:5    0    4T  0 disk

  :~$ ls -la /dev/sd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun 20 21:29 /dev/sdh -> nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun 20 21:29 /dev/sds -> nvme2n1
```

**After reboot**

```
  :~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme2n1      259:1    0  500G  0 disk
├─nvme2n1p1  259:6    0  500G  0 part
└─nvme2n1p9  259:7    0    8M  0 part
nvme1n1      259:5    0    4T  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1  259:8    0    4T  0 part
└─nvme1n1p9  259:9    0    8M  0 part

  :~$ ls -la /dev/sd[h-s]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun 20 21:35 /dev/sdh -> nvme2n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun 20 21:35 /dev/sds -> nvme1n1
```

See the **/dev/nvme1n1** which is 500GB in size and **/dev/sdh** that point's to it before reboot.

And after reboot, **/dev/sdh** points to **/dev/nvme2n1** which is still the same 500GB drive but has a different name. And all data, mounts, etc work just fine.